# justify-self and position relative does not work correctly

Tags: css, safari, css-position, css-grid

I have grid-box and `item2` is in the end of hi's area `b`:

```css
.wrapper > div {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-rows: 150px 150px;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "a b"
      "c d"
}
.item1 {
    grid-area: a;
}
.item2 {
    grid-area: b;
    justify-self: end;
    position: relative;
    right: -20px;
}
.item3 {
    grid-area: d;
    justify-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

I need to move `item2` a little bit to right from his position, so I use `relative` position and `right: -20px`. It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari Version 11.1.2 (13605.3.8) seems like `justify-self: end` is not working: I mean, `item2` is on the left side of area `b`. Without `right: -20px` element `item2` is in the right side of his area. How can I fix it?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/mraimon/pen/ZwzxWe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negative margin instead:

```css
.wrapper > div {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-rows: 150px 150px;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "a b"
      "c d"
}
.item1 {
    grid-area: a;
}
.item2 {
    grid-area: b;
    justify-self: end;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
.item3 {
    grid-area: d;
    justify-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Or translate:

```css
.wrapper > div {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-rows: 150px 150px;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "a b"
      "c d"
}
.item1 {
    grid-area: a;
}
.item2 {
    grid-area: b;
    justify-self: end;
    transform:translateX(20px);
}
.item3 {
    grid-area: d;
    justify-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3</div>
</div>
```